# How to prevent displaying sub and overscript as plain strings in .wl files?

Tags: front-end, packages, usage-messages

### Problem:

String with subscripts and overscripts are formatted as plain text after saving, closing, and reopening the document. It makes it hard to edit function usage because text become unreadable if there are multiple symbols like that.

I'm working on a package that's in `.wl` format.

### Example:

Create a function usage string:
[image]

Save the document, close it, then reopen. The string now looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible not to change the display formatting after reopening the document? (I understand that the purpose of this behaviour is to be able to edit the documents in any text editor.)

Comment: What about using `myFunc::usage = ToString[Row[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, ","], StandardForm]`?

Comment: After opening it, you can use `Ctrl+Shift+N` to perform a conversion.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq this is what I was looking for, thanks!